# Lvs Load balancer VIP

Tags: linux, ip-address, lvs

I have created an alias IP address of my computer using

```
sudo ifconfig eth0:0 172.17.10.173 netmask 255.255.240.0 broadcast 172.17.15.255
```

My orignal IP is 172.17.6.111 and netmask is 255.255.240.0.
I am trying to set up an Load balance using ipvsadm via direct routing ipvsadm technique as it is given [here](http://www.ultramonkey.org/papers/lvs_tutorial/html/)
When someone tries to connect it via browser it shows no response .

Comment: output of ipvsadm -L?

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure the web server to listen to multiple ip-addresses too. If you use Apache, search for the section "IP-based Virtual Host Support" in the Apache docs.

Comment: @Albert Veli Actually I am implementing a load balancer so I don't think there is any need to configure apache2 on the load balancer